# Pandas to find a call centre manager's region

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a situation where I need to identify if a customer relationship manager is handling regional or global customers. Now a manger can handle both regional as well as global calls so an identification is necessary if that is true or not. The data is in the following format:

```
Customer_Name       Customer_Region       Manager_Name          Manager_Region
A                   Middle East           MGR1                  Middle East
B                   Asia                  MGR1                  Middle East
C                   Eastern Europe        MGR1                  Middle East
D                   Middle East           MGR1                  Middle East
E                   Middle East           MGR2                  Middle East
F                   Middle East           MGR2                  Middle East
G                   Middle East           MGR3                  Eastern Europe
H                   Middle East           MGR3                  Eastern Europe
```

So if a manager is capable of taking calls outside of their own region, then the flag should be Global else regional. Here is an example output:

```
Manager_Name          Manager_Call_handling_Region
MGR1                  Global
MGR2                  Regional
MGR3                  Global
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['Manager_Name'], as_index=False).agg(','.join)
df['equal'] = df['Customer_Region']==df['Manager_Region']
df['Manager_Call_handling_Region'] = df['equal'].apply(lambda x: 'Regional' if x==True else 'Global')
df.drop(columns=['Customer_Name', 'Customer_Region', 'Manager_Region', 'equal'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Manager_Name Manager_Call_handling_Region
0         MGR1                       Global
1         MGR2                     Regional
2         MGR3                       Global
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be:

1. Test if the Manager's region matches the Customer's region
2. Grouping by the manager, find the minimal value of the test
3. If the minimum is 0 then the Manager looks after a different region compared to the Customer, convert the 0/1 to Global/Regional

```
df["Same_Region"] = df['Customer_Region']==df['Manager_Region']
df.groupby(["Manager_Name"])["Same_Region"].min()
df["Region"] = df["Same_Region"].map({0:"Global", 1:"Regional"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = (df
       .set_index('Manager_Name')
        #customer column not useful
       .filter(like='Region')
       #get columns into one
       .stack()
       .groupby('Manager_Name')
        #get unique values 
       .agg(set)
       .reset_index(name='val')
        #if manager is regional, he/she will have just one location
        #if global, more than one
       .assign(Manager_Call_Handling_Region = lambda x: np.where(x.val.str.len().gt(1),
                                                                "Global",
                                                                "Regional"))
       .drop('val',axis=1)
      )

res


  Manager_Name  Manager_Call_Handling_Region
0   MGR1            Global
1   MGR2            Regional
2   MGR3            Global
```